# Writing to file a.txt, whilst terminal is redirected to file b.txt

Tags: c++, linux, googletest

I have a program running as such:

```
./program &> b.txt
```

And the "program" executable writes to another file, "a.txt" as shown:

```
std::ofstream file;
file.open ("a.txt", std::ios::out);
file << "content: " << some_param << "\n";
file.close();
```

and of course, the "program" executable outputs some other text as such:

```
std::cout << "...";
std::cerr << "...";
```

The problem is this; "a.txt" has some content, that should normally be on "b.txt", and also, the function that writes to "a.txt" looks like it runs only once, while normally, that function should have ran 12-13 times.

It may be helpful to mention that the function that writes to "a.txt" is called from GoogleTest Unit Testing framework, however, the std::cout or cerr functions could be called from anywhere.

What could be the problem?

Comment: the problem is in your code. Please include a [mcve] in the question

Comment: Normally, opening an `ofstream` will remove the previous contents of the file. If you want to append to it instead, use `std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::app` as the mode.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but get in the habit of initializing objects with meaningful values rather than default-initializing them and immediately overwriting the default values. In this case, that means changing `std::ofstream file; file.open ("a.txt", std::ios::out);` to `std::ofstream file("a.txt");` Also, you don't need to call `file.close();`; the destructor will do that.

Comment: @PeteBecker That's what I normally do, but thanks, it is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I've solved the problem, thought I'd share. The error was quite simple actually, as pointed out by the commenters.

1) "a.txt" has some content from "b.txt", because apparently I specifically told the "program" to do that. That part was not caused by some "undefined behaviour" of the GoogleTest framework. (I was expecting such a thing, since I was using some ::internal functionality)

2) Code that writes to "a.txt" appears to run only once, because, as suggested by @G. Sliepen, the file is not opened with `std::ofstream::app`, again, my bad.